# ¿Qué pueden modificar los moderadores?

Tags: soporte, moderación, centro-de-ayuda, faq-de-moderadores

<sub>Adaptación de [¿Qué podemos modificar los moderadores?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2775/1674) publicado en Meta Spanish.SE.</sub>

A medida que más y más gente visita el sitio, vamos descubriendo lagunas en la documentación o cosas a mejorar.

Cuando es algo al alcance de los moderadores, el tiempo entre la aceptación de una propuesta y su materialización puede ser más breve. Por contra, cuando escapa de nuestro control debemos considerar que se debe tratar con un CM.

El propósito pues de esta pregunta-respuesta es mantener un listado de qué pueden modificar los moderadores, para el conocimiento de todos y mejor explicación de qué está a su alcance. Lo que no está listado es porque o bien solo pueden modificarlo los CM, o bien directamente no se puede modificar.

Pregunta relacionada en Meta.SE: [What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/209901)

Comment: Muy interesante, no sabía que los moderadores pueden cambiar las opciones de cierre offtopic (y posiblemente los moderadores tampoco). Gracias por este post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Documentación

### [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

- El texto en [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Entero.
- El texto que encabeza el Centro de ayuda, que ahora mismo está vacío en este sitio.

  > [image]

  Hay sitios, como Buddhism, que tienen bastante información allí:

  > [image]

### [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Diferentes secciones.

- El encabezado, ahora consistente en:

  > Stack Overflow en español es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software. Lo construyes y lo administras *tú* como parte de la red de sitios de preguntas y respuestas de [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com). Con tu ayuda, trabajamos juntos para crear una biblioteca de respuestas detalladas para todas las preguntas sobre programación, desarrollo y uso de software.
- *Formula preguntas, obtén respuestas, sin distracciones*.

  La pregunta de ejemplo.
- *Obtén respuestas para preguntas prácticas y detalladas*

  Los puntos en *Preguntar sobre...* y *No preguntes sobre...*.

---

También pueden modificar:

- las opciones de cierre por *off-topic*.

Comment: Animo a quien quiera a que cambie las imágenes por las propias de SOes :)