# Recopilemos ejemplos de buenas preguntas

Tags: discusión, preguntas

He visto varias preguntas que parecen más solicitudes en el área de desarrollo que preguntas en sí, preguntas que terminan siendo cerradas por tratarse de 2 o 3 líneas con una calidad muy baja.

Propongo que este post se use como un mini repositorio de las mejores preguntas que hayan visto en el sitio, de este modo podemos referir a los usuarios nuevos a que le den una lectura rápida.

De las mejores preguntas que he visto, todas tienen los siguientes ingredientes:

- Buen título.
- Escenario descrito.
- Código hecho.
- Línea de error o comportamiento del error.
- Código adicional que intentó y/o descripción de aquello que intentó.

Finalmente agregan cómo debería funcionar en caso todo fluya con el compilador.

¿Opiniones?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a [algo como esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/5587982)? A mi particularmente me parece interesante ese tipo de iniciativas. En el homólogo inglés existen varias preguntas así. [Yo intenté en el sitio en español algo no tan parecido, pero inspirado en esa idea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81028/29967) y la pregunta terminó siendo cerrada. Hubieron reacciones tanto a favor como en contra y [el tema fue traído también a meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2279/29967).

Comment: Sí, algo así mi estimado, de tal manera que le digan a los usuarios: mira este link, tiene buenos ejemplos de preguntas, trata de redactar algo similar y todos felices :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que la iniciativa tiene su miga, pero no creo que sea este el lugar más ideal para ofrecerla, pues...

## Ya existe un lugar donde ver preguntas de referencia: el Recorrido

¿Cómo? ¿Qué? Pues sí, si vais al [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) veréis que aparece una pregunta como ejemplo. Esa pregunta la pueden modificar los moderadores. Por tanto, tal vez lo ideal sería decidir cuál queremos mostrar.

Creo que es más relevante ponerlo allí porque esta pregunta debe ser especialmente referente para los nuevos usuarios, que es más probable que visiten el *Recorrido* que una conversación de Meta.

Opcionalmente puede añadirse un [Consejo sobre cómo usar el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3761/83) en la que se explique eso, si bien puede quedar un poco ortopédico.

Referencias:

- [¿Qué pueden modificar los moderadores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3679/83)

Comment: " tal vez lo ideal sería decidir cuál queremos mostrar." -> Comparto la idea :D

Comment: @fredyfx adelante pues : ) ¿Cómo quieres hacerlo? ¿Una nueva pregunta del tipo "¿Qué pregunta deberíamos seleccionar para el Recorrido?"?

Comment: Tengo en mente que los usuarios publiquen de las mejores preguntas que han visto de las etiquetas que más visitan, si publicamos un par solamente, de unos 30 usuarios que participen, tendríamos 60 preguntas bien hechas de diversos escenarios. Por ejemplo, he perdido la cuenta de las preguntas AJAX, PHP, responses 404/500 y variables nulas... casi todas comparten el mismo procedimiento en el debugging, ¿cuáles están bien redactadas? Que haya una lista de ejemplos ayudaría en algo a mejorar la calidad del sitio.

Comment: @fredyfx mmm no me convence la idea, como dije en mi respuesta. Lo que se puede hacer es elegir la pregunta que sale en el Recorrido. Adicionalmente, se puede añadir un listado de preguntas _importantes y recurrentes_ en la wiki de las etiquetas. Listar una serie de preguntas buenas así sin más no lo veo necesario, más que nada porque difícilmente llegará ese listado a las manos de quien lo necesita, que son los nuevos usuarios.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, por curiosidad ¿qué ingredientes le pondrías para que sea de tu agrado?

Comment: @fredyfx no no, mi agrado es lo de menos :) Lo que pienso es en los usuarios nuevos y me parece que será difícil llevarlos hasta una pregunta de Meta con una lista grande de preguntas. Me parece interesante para fomentar la concordia y el reconocimiento entre los usuarios más activos por aquí, pero que difícilmente llegará a quienes creo que va encaminada la iniciativa, que son los usuarios nuevos.

Comment: si no te agrada o no te convence, está bien. Eres el único que ha publicado una respuesta con 6 votos hasta la fecha de hoy 7 de febrero 2019, lo cual indica que hay otros 6 usuarios que tampoco están convencidos y/o no les agrada la idea y/o lo ven innecesario porque como dices, ya está en el recorrido. La pregunta tiene poco más de 1 semana, sigue con 0 votos y sólo 1 usuario ha comentado con algo referente en SO. Definitivamente esto ya quedó claro. Ni modo bro, gracias por el aporte :D