# Quién tiene más poder, ¿un moderador con poca reputación o un usuario con mucha?

Tags: soporte, moderadores, privilegios

¿Qué usuario tiene más posibilidades de hacer cosas o más, digamos, "poder" en el sitio, un usuario de 3000 ptos pero que fue elegido como moderador o uno de 50 000 ptos que no ejerce como moderador oficial del sitio?

Comment: define "poder". Un moderador puede hacer todo lo que cualquier usuario pueda hacer, más bastantes más cosas. La diferencia es que lo que hace el moderador no siempre es visible por la comunidad, ni tampoco revertible. Esto en cuanto a poder "duro". En cuanto a poder "blando", un usuario cualquiera puede aportar ideas, sugerir, etc y tener más peso específico que un moderador, por lo que puede acabar modelando más la comunidad en la que participa.

Comment: En [¿Quién son los moderadores ♦? ¿Cuál es su rol?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4029/83) puedes ver todos los privilegios que tiene un moderador.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', un usuario de 3000 logicamente va a tener menos privilegios que uno de 50 000, pero que pasa si ese de 3000 es moderador, tendria todos los privilegios que tiene el de 50 000 y ademas los privilegios propios de moderador

Comment: Los privilegios implican responsabilidades en SO; no así en la sociedad capitalista (favor no politizar el uso de capitalista, no pude decirlo de otra forma) en la que se traducen en ventajas y eventualmente en injusticia. Si se va a debatir ese tema, se debe desnudar, de la porquería que le aporta el uso social del término.

Comment: La clave aquí es que un moderador tiene _todos_ los privilegios independientemente de su reputación. Además, privilegios que no dependen de la reputación sino del cargo.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', esa es la respuesta que buscaba, gracias

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ponlo como respuesta, para marcarla como aceptada

Comment: I got the power... necesitaba ponerme a cantar eso (?)

Comment: @gbianchi o "Gimme tha power" de Molotov :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Un moderador diamantado tiene todos los privilegios de un usuario, independientemente de su reputación. Además, privilegios que no dependen de la reputación sino del cargo y que puedes consultar en [¿Quién son los moderadores ♦? ¿Cuál es su rol?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4029/83).
También vale la pena leer [¿Qué pueden modificar los moderadores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3679/83) para ver las modificaciones que pueden hacer en el Centro de Ayuda, Recorrido y demás.

La diferencia es que lo que hace el moderador no siempre es visible por la comunidad, ni tampoco revertible. Por ejemplo, un moderador puede ver comentarios borrados, juntar preguntas, editar comentarios de cualquier usuario, juntar etiquetas...

En cuanto a poder *blando*, un usuario cualquiera puede aportar ideas, sugerir, etc y tener más peso específico que un moderador, por lo que puede acabar modelando más la comunidad en la que participa.

Comment: [respuesta relacionada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3112/28035)

Answer (score 3):

Un moderador ♦ tiene [todos los privilegios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/295232) enumerados en el artículo [Privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) del Centro de ayuda, independientemente de su reputación. Eso sí, hay [algunos de privilegios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326808/295232) que los moderadores ♦ no ganan, pero son poco importantes.

Comment: no entiendo qué quieres decir en la segunda frase

Comment: Yo tampoco entiendo

Comment: Want to help with some translation?? I supposed you mean that there are some privileges that are not even won when you are appointed as moderator?

Comment: @gbianchi exactemente. Pero creo que he utilizado una construccion grammatical incorrecta, y fedorqui ya dio una buena respuesta.

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'